# What files will get deployed and where can I find the files in worklight console?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

We are developing a mobile app using IBM MobileFirst platform.

We compile the code using the command line tool with the command 'mfp build' and deploy it using 'mfp deploy', and we are able to preview the application from the URL mentioned below: http://localhost:xxxxx/worklightconsole/index.html

After doing 'mfp build' I get these 6 files:

- mobapp.war
- mobAppAdapter.adapter
- Dashboard-all.wlapp
- Dashboard-common.wlapp
- Dashboard-desktopbrowser-1.0.wlapp
- Dashboard-ipad-1.2.wlapp

Questions:

1. Where can I find the 6 files in 'worklight console'? (or)
2. Which other URL I have to refer to verify whether the files have been deployed correctly or not?

Because when I type in 'mfp build' it deploys the files but we are not sure where its getting deployed.   We don't have WAS installed instead 'liberty' is used to our knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MobileFirst Platform CLI tool contains an embedded WebSphere Liberty profile server inside of it. It is this server and its internal database (during development time(!)), that the artifacts you have mentioned get deployed to.

You create a project ("mfp create").
You then start the server ("mfp start").

You then create your applications, develop them, etc...
Eventually you build and deploy it to the server ("mfp build", "mfp deploy").

The resulting files of the build command are the .adapter and .wlapp files.
These get deployed using the deploy command to the server's database.

You then see these files in the console using "mfp console".

The .war file is your project's runtime, containing metadata required for  various server operations. This file is part of the server and handled automatically by the underlying tooling. This is invisible to you during development.

Comment: Hi Adar,  thanks for your info

If I change any of the files inside 'war' or 'wlapp'  will the entire 'war / wlapp' be deployed ?  

Or is there any way to deploy the changes as PATCH instead of ENTIRE WAR???

Comment: Simply "mfp bd" from the root folder of the project to rebuild and deploy all project artifacts.

Comment: I was asking whether we can deploy "changed files" alone to the server and not entire 'war' or 'wlapp'.   Thanks for your help and reply.

Comment: In the development environment you have no control over this. do "mfp bd".

Comment: no, you can not deploy just part of the war or part of the wlapp

Comment: @SathishKumar, If this answer helped you, please mark as Answered.